Story ID: Pre-1985 non-adventure novel, I think with light in title
[This is going to be a hard one.  I will strain to give every tiny detail that I remember.  Some of which may be incorrect--y'all know how that goes.]
Trying to remember the name of an SF novel that I tried to read, out of a US school library (c. 1978-1984 reading attempt, publication would necessarily be pre-1985.)
Novel was in the SF section, but was sort of arty.  Not typical SF adventure fare.  Not annoying impenetrable writing.  But the style although clean, was mainstream.
I seem to remember it having something to do with light in the title.  Something paradoxical like the sound of light or slowness.  I'm not 100% sure even of the light.  But it was definitely kind of a weird title.  Not Space Cadet or Ice Planet...if ya get me!
I looked up the Unbearable Lightness of Being which has a similar strange title...but it does not seem to match.  It's also not I See by My Outfit (but that has a similar cool title, but is not SF&F, albeit by a sometime SF&F author AND is enjoyable, memorable.)
I think it had something to do with post-apocalyptic stuff.  I seem to remember a child going through an abandoned department store (kind of like Kyle Reese in Terminator).  Which was a cool image and I thought could go somewhere fun...but then it really didn't have a fun Earth Abides or Alas Babylon adventure.  It just wasn't very hooky or adventuresome.
I think there was a mother or relationship with mother involved.
It was definitely SF (properly categorized).  I'm not sure what the SF element was though, exactly--unless it was the post apocalypse aspect, which itself I'm not even sure of!  But I would have gotten the book reclassified if it was just a librarian mistake.
I think it was physically a hardcover, with a slip jacket, but kind of nicer paper (not glossy) and minimalist or no art.  Maybe grey or beige, maybe with some yellow or red stripe rectangle around the front.
I suspect I did not finish the novel, but if I did, it has not stuck.  Like at least A Short Sharp Shock (another with sort of a hooky title and some mainstream aspects), while being a pointless shaggy dog story, has some cool images and adventures along the way, so that you remember it, even if infuriated with it.  But this light story or slow story title thing was not as interesting or adventuresome as that.
Oh...and it wasn't some sort of Tau Zero FTL exploration or physicsy thing either.  Which I could have tolerated.  The light or slowness or whatever was more wordsy than physicsy.

Just a wild guess - "Where Late the Sweet Birds Sang" by Kate Wilhelm (1975).  Post-apocalyptic but set in rural communities where the physical setting is relatively undamaged and the story's focus is on people and cross-generational relations rather than technology (well, other than cloning). One of the families owns [or owned] a department store, now abandoned, which comes into the story a couple of times.

I will investigate.  Don't think it was a female author.  But will check--need to find a copy to look at.

It turns out my old man had a copy.  Started to read it...nope.  In addition, cover and such are different.  I will probably try to plow through it, given the award and how hard it is for me to find anything good to read...but have a bad feeling...starts with a discussion of a bratty kid at a family dinner.  As if that is important or worth wasting reader time on. Ugg.  And they wonder why boys don't like school!

I went by my old place and looked at the shelves, to see if I had it or had confused the appearance with another unread book.  I have two full bookcases of unread books.  But it's not in there.  I'm probably a little old for sneaking into the school library...and I doubt a book is still there (although you never know).  Other than that...sort of hoping that my brain will remember the title better.
